# LinkedIn Job Search API - Python

Tags: python, linkedin-api

Error 403 Client Error: Forbidden: Unknown Error

I am trying to run the following code to extract data from Linkedin's API. For some reason, I am NOT able to generate/extract data for job search and people search. Although, the code throws data/results for company search. Can you please help....My code below.

```js
CONSUMER_KEY = '<redacted>'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '<redacted>'
USER_TOKEN = '<redacted>'
USER_SECRET = '<redacted>'
RETURN_URL = ''

from linkedin import linkedin
from oauthlib import *
import json


authentication = linkedin.LinkedInDeveloperAuthentication(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, 
                                                      USER_TOKEN, USER_SECRET, 
                                                      RETURN_URL, linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())

application = linkedin.LinkedInApplication(authentication)

 
print "*" * 120

company = application.search_company(selectors=[{'companies': ['name', 'universal-name', 'website-url']}], params={'keywords': 'python'})
print json.dumps(company, indent=3)

#profiles = application.search_profile(selectors=[{'people': ['first-name', 'last-name']}], params={'keywords': 'apple microsoft'})
#print json.dumps(profiles, indent=3) 
#
#jobs = application.search_job(selectors=[{'jobs': ['id', 'customer-job-code', 'posting-date']}], params={'title': 'python', 'count': 2})
#print json.dumps(jobs, indent=3)
```

Comment: You should not be sharing your secret key values in a public forum.

Comment: This question as already answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080575/access-denied-to-call-linkedins-api

Comment: @JustinKominar - The secret values are random numbers, these are not my credentials. Also, I have filled out the form, do you know by when it could be approved? I need it for some analysis purposes.